# how to create multiple aliases in mailtie

Tags: email, domain-forwarding

I want to redirect emails from my own domain to Gmail using [mailtie](https://mailtie.com/) redirect service.
I have the domain parked in godaddy. But I have not been able to configure several aliases. However, on its home page it says "Unlimited aliases, catch-alls, multiple recipients, wildcards, and auto-responses". I have written to [mailtie](https://mailtie.com/), no response.

example in goddady

If I do this it works:

```
MX @ mx.mailtie.com. (Priority: 10) 1 Hour
TXT @ mailtie=foo@gmail.com 1 Hour
TXT @ mailtie=support:foo@gmail.com 1 Hour
```

If I do this it doesn't work:

```
MX @ mx.mailtie.com. (Priority: 10) 1 Hour
TXT @ mailtie=foo@gmail.com 1 Hour
TXT @ mailtie=contact:foo@gmail.com 1 Hour
TXT @ mailtie=support:foo@gmail.com 1 Hour
```

How to do it correctly. The site does not provide clear information about creating several aliases for the same destination or for several destinations

If I do this it doesn't work:

```
MX @ mx.mailtie.com. (Priority: 10) 1 Hour
TXT @ mailtie=foo@gmail.com 1 Hour
TXT @ mailtie=contact:foo@gmail.com 1 Hour
TXT @ mailtie=support:bar@gmail.com 1 Hour
```

PS: Previously I used [improvmx](https://improvmx.com/), but it has many limitations in the free redirection (10 mb maximum of attachments) and I also used [forwardemail](https://forwardemail.net/es/login), but it is paid for some domain extensions

thk

Comment: What does the mailtie support doc say it should look like? Does this service support multiple email aliases? Link the support doc and not their home page.